# How to do circular convolution between 2 functions with cconv?

Tags: matlab, convolution

I was asked to do circular convolution between two functions by sampling them, using the functions `cconv`. A known result of this sort of convolution is: `CCONV( sin(x), sin(x) ) == -pi*cos(x)`

To test the above I did:

```
w = linspace(0,2*pi,1000);
l = linspace(0,2*pi,1999);
stem(l,cconv(sin(w),sin(w))
```

but the result I got was:

[image: Result]

which is absolutely not `-pi*cos(x)`.

Can anybody please explain what is wrong with my code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the documentation of `cconv` it says that:

> `c = cconv(a,b,n)` circularly convolves vectors `a` and `b`. `n` is the length of the resulting vector. If you omit `n`, it defaults to `length(a)+length(b)-1`. **When `n = length(a)+length(b)-1`, the circular convolution is equivalent to the linear convolution computed with `conv`**.

I believe that the reason for your problem is that you do not specify the 3rd input to `cconv`, which then selects the default value, which is not the right one for you. I have made an animation showing what happens when different values of `n` are chosen.

[image: animation]

If you compare my result for `n=200` to your plot you will see that the amplitude of your data is 10 times larger whereas the length of your `linspace` is 10 times bigger. This means that some normalization is needed, likely a multiplication by the `linspace` step.

Indeed, after proper scaling and choice of `n` we get the right result:

```
res = 100;                % resolution
w = linspace(0,2*pi,res);
dx = diff(w(1:2));        % grid step
stem( linspace(0,2*pi,res), dx * cconv(sin(w),sin(w),res) );
```

[image: The right result]

---

This is the code I used for the animation:

```
hF = figure(); 
subplot(1,2,1); hS(1) = stem(1,cconv(1,1,1)); title('Autoscaling');
subplot(1,2,2); hS(2) = stem(1,cconv(1,1,1)); xlim([0,7]); ylim(50*[-1,1]); title('Constant limits');

w = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
for ind1 = 1:200
  set(hS,'XData',linspace(0,2*pi,ind1));
  set(hS,'YData',cconv(sin(w),sin(w),ind1));
  suptitle("n = " + ind1);
  drawnow
  % export_fig(char("D:\BLABLA\F" + ind1 + ".png"),'-nocrop');
end
```

Comment: Thanks alot my friend